# Scala relative frequency

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe object which looks like:

```
+--+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+ 
|id|bin1|bin2|bin3|bin4|bin5|bin6|bin7|bin8|bin9|bin10|
+--+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+
|a |   1|null|null|null|null|   1|  14|  91| 929| null|
|c |   4|   2|   5|  82|  49| 176| 222| 439|null| null|
|f |   1|   1|null|null|   2|   8| 226| 294|   2| null|
|e |null|   1|   2|null|   4|  13|  19| 242| 752|    1|
|y |   1|   1|   3|   9|  11|  17| 136| 664| 338| null|
|e |   4|   2|   1|   8|  14| 169| 952| 431|null| null|
```

How can I replace the absolute values with relative values (frequency)?

Edit: After the transformation, the dataframe object for the first row should look like this:

```
+--+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+------+-----+-----+ 
|id|bin1|bin2|bin3|bin4|bin5|bin6|bin7 |bin8  |bin9 |bin10|
+--+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+------+-----+-----+
|a | 0.0|null|null|null|null| 0.0| 0.01|  0.09| 0.90| null|
```

The algorithm should divide every value of a cell by the sum of the row. After this transformation, the sum of a row is always 1.

I think I can achieve it with map but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show what the expected output should look like.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have edited my post and hope it makes it more clear.

Comment: Can you add what you have tried so far? And, is this homework?

Comment: @Jeremy: I have tried something like evan058 but I wasn't able to create a sum column because my first column is a string column. But his example helped me to solve this with cols.tails.toArray. Next time I'll add what I have tried. It was a former homework which I could solve. :)

Comment: I meant which I couldn't solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want the `null`s to be treated as 0s, here is one solution:

```
scala> var df = Seq((1d,2d,Double.NaN),(Double.NaN, 3d,4d), (5d, Double.NaN, 6d)).toDF("a", "b", "c")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: double, b: double, c: double]

scala> df.show
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|1.0|2.0|NaN|
|NaN|3.0|4.0|
|5.0|NaN|6.0|
+---+---+---+

scala> val cols = df.columns
cols: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c)

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions

scala> df = df.na.fill(0d).withColumn("sum", cols.map(col).reduce(_ + _))
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: double, b: double, c: double, sum: double]

scala> df.show
+---+---+---+----+
|  a|  b|  c| sum|
+---+---+---+----+
|1.0|2.0|0.0| 3.0|
|0.0|3.0|4.0| 7.0|
|5.0|0.0|6.0|11.0|
+---+---+---+----+


scala> cols.foreach( cName => df = df.withColumn(cName, df.col(cName) / df.col("sum")))

scala> df.drop("sum").show
+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|                  a|                  b|                 c|
+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
| 0.3333333333333333| 0.6666666666666666|               0.0|
|                0.0|0.42857142857142855|0.5714285714285714|
|0.45454545454545453|                0.0|0.5454545454545454|
+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you. Your example helped me a lot.